# CoreLocation start Monitoring For multi Regions

Tags: ios, xcode, location, core-location, locationmanager

how can i start monitoring for multi regions by using locationManager startMonitoringForRegion method

for example i have three regions i want to monitor it

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D centreLoc = {28.965243, 48.149724};
CLLocationDistance regionRadius = 200.00;
CLRegion *grRegion = [[CLRegion alloc] initCircularRegionWithCenter:centreLoc radius:regionRadius identifier:@"grRegion1"];


CLLocationCoordinate2D centreLoc2 = {28.765243, 48.149724};
CLLocationDistance regionRadius2 = 200.00;
CLRegion *grRegion2 = [[CLRegion alloc] initCircularRegionWithCenter:centreLoc2 radius:regionRadius2 identifier:@"grRegion2"];

CLLocationCoordinate2D centreLoc3 = {28.865243, 48.149724};
CLLocationDistance regionRadius3 = 200.00;
CLRegion *grRegion3 = [[CLRegion alloc] initCircularRegionWithCenter:centreLoc3 radius:regionRadius3 identifier:@"grRegion3"];

CLLocationAccuracy acc2=kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
[locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:grRegion2 desiredAccuracy:acc2];
```

how can start monitor for this three regions ???

Comment: Just call startMonitoringForRegion for each region.

Comment: how can i do that if i have many regions please give me example

Comment: You can call the startMonitoringForRegion for each region.

Comment: i have try this but its not work

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track.

First, your coordinates should be a double value, you are using a float value.

Second, you need to make separate arrays for Latitude and Longitude, and then take those values at index i.

This should work.

```
for (int i = 0; i < [AllRegionsArray count]; i++) {
    NSArray *longLati = [allRegionsArray objectAtIndex:i];
    NSMutableArray *latArray = longLati objectAtIndex:0];
    NSMutableArray *longArray = longLati objectAtIndex:1];
    lutiuid = [latArray objectAtIndex:i];
    longtuid = [longArray objectAtIndex:i];

    CLLocationCoordinate2D centreLoc = [CLLocation2DMake([[lutiuid] doubleValue], [[longtuid] doubleValue]);
//iOS 6
    CLRegion *grRegion = [[CLRegion alloc] initWithCenter:centreLoc radius:200 identifier://yourIdentifier, I used the string of the address];
//iOS 7
CLCircularRegion *region = [[CLCircularRegion alloc] initWithCenter:coordinate radius:radius identifier:identifier];
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    [locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:grRegion];
    NSLog(@"monotoring regions:%@", locationManager.monitoredRegions);
```

Comment: I have the similar problem as that one who asked the question, but this solution still didn't solve the problem for me. locationManager.monitoredRegion count returns 0 even after you call startMonitoringForRegion

Comment: Are your arrays returning the right values for Latitude and Longitude?

Comment: My problem was solved when I used CLCircularRegion instead of CLRegion (deprecated).

Comment: I can't remember exactly what solved the problem, but I did something else too to fix the problem. CLRegion also works too now.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, when I originally answered we were all still using iOS 6, I have edited my answer to reflect that.